# Node and/or socket io multi-player whackamole

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, socket.io

So, let's say I wanted to create a multi-player whackamole game.

and... I emitted the mole which shows up on screen in multiple client browsers, potentially 20 or 30 clients, all displaying the same mole at the same time. and... Several of the players click that same mole at the same time...

How do I determine who won and deal with collisions or ???

I don't really want to create a whackamole game but this is the easiest way I can think of to explain the issue I am having at the moment.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Several of the players click that same mole at the same time....  How do I determine who won?

Usually, you just have the server decide who wins by whichever request gets to the server first.

> and deal with collisions?

Not sure what you mean by collisions.  The server is going to have to decide who came first and your user interface on the client is going to have to show that to the user, even if the user thinks they got it, but lost in a close call because they were just beat out by another user when their request got to the server.  Unless you want to modify the game and award a "tie" for two requests that arrived on the server within a certain amount of time of one another.

Comment: Thanks but, I understand that the server determines who won but.. How?

Comment: @Todd - First request to arrive on the server wins.  Second request for the same event from a different client is ignored.  The requests will be processed serially on the server based on which arrived first.  One has to come before the other.

Comment: I get that but how do I store the info in the node app? For example, first click comes in for mole #4, how do I hang on to that info in my node app and associate that with later claims on mole #4?

Comment: Not an issue for clicks that happen say 10 seconds apart because I have time to show the mole claimed in the clients so nobody else can click. But with this being a situation where multiple people will be clicking at the same time or very close to the same time, I am just lost as to how I can track it all. Any sample code might help me understand a little better. Not looking for anyone to write it for me, just to help me solve this simultaneous click issue. I can update a database record for example to show the mole as claimed but, that isn't fast enough for an app like this.

Comment: When someone is the first to claim a mole on the server, you have to broadcast a message to all the other clients so they can show that it was claimed by someone else.  If two users claim at about the same time, a client may momentarily show it as claimed by the local user, but then in a short time, their client will get a message that it was actually claimed first by someone else and it can update their UI.  There's nothing else you can do there for a live game other than call it a tie and award both users some points.  There's a small inherent delay in communicating other user's actions.